# Passing everything to a base class is good if only children needs that data?

Tags: php, inheritance

given this inheritance structure:

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected $version;

    public function __constructor($version)
    {
        $this->version = $version;
    }

    public abstract function doSql();
}

class MySQL extends Base
{
    public function doSql()
    {
        switch($this->version)
        {
             case 1 :
                 break;
             case 2 :
                 break;
        }
    }
}

class Oracle extends Base
{
    public function doSql()
    {
        switch($this->version)
        {
             case 1 :
                 break;
             case 2 :
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

in this example `$version` is going to be used in all children BUT not in base class, so it smells to me. Base itself doesnt need `$version`.
As refactored:

```
abstract class Base
{
    public abstract function doSql($version);
}

class MySQL extends Base
{
    public function doSql($version)
    {
        switch($version)
        {
             case 1 :
                 break;
             case 2 :
                 break;
        }
    }
}

class Oracle extends Base
{
    public function doSql($version)
    {
        switch($version)
        {
             case 1 :
                 break;
             case 2 :
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

it slightly shorter, but I cant see any advantages now - apart from if it had passed to constructor, it wouldnt be able to change while now can (kind of immutable), so it seems to be more flexible. However, immutable classes are also good idea...
When to use which approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is better when the property belongs to a class.

This may seem a stupid thing to say when we know this, but really think about it. If you’re using version as a parameter for the majority of the object methods, then it’s likely that it should be a property. It makes more sense to assign an object a property that’s unique as it allows for a stricter rule set when using that class.

E.g. developer A could come along and pass different version values per method, if the class was a database handler and the version dictated which engine they use, all of a sudden they can specify 3 different engines per function, which to me, spells trouble.

Answer (score 1):

First, a more descriptive name for the parent class might have been `DataBase` rather than simply `Base`. But since a "version" is an attribute that is common to all databases that presumably you will have, it really only makes sense to define in the `Base` class so that all subclasses inherit this attribute without having to define it.

Why is that? Is it not reasonable that in the future you might wish to expose the database version to clients of your classes by defining a `getVersion` method? And where would you place that method? In each of your subclasses? Of course not. It would belong in class `Base` again because it would be a method that would be applicable to all subclasses and you would want them to inherit this new behavior. So, plan for the future!